# Correct logic to use when implementing 2fa on my site?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I am using the "sonata-project/google-authenticator" library. It allows me to generate a QR code as follows:

```
$g = new \Google\Authenticator\GoogleAuthenticator();
$salt = 'XJDDJKSLJNASDJNASDASDASD';
$secret = $uid.$salt;
$url = $g->getURL($uid, 'coinula.com', $secret);
```

My question is around this:

[image]

1. The secret I provide, is that the secret that these guys are showing to the user? So that secret is the "global" key and the qr code is just a picture version of this code?
2. Am I supposed to store the secret and keep it safe on my side? Or is that something that the user should be able to write down and decide if he wants to keep it. I.e. Is the purpose of the secret for me NOT to store it? Or is there a reason I must store it?

Comment: The secret, regardless of how its shared between user and server, is the key cryptographic component of the TOTP algorithm.  It needs to be unique per user and ideally not directly related to the user's known information (e.g. random).  The GA app computes the code based on the algorithm, # of digits, and time interval (always 6 and 30 seconds, for GA), which your server must generate and compare against (using the secret, digits, and interval)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a dumb question, but I'll answer it anyway. The secret must be stored in order for you to match it to the user. Would've been nicer if you could specify your own secret. I suppose there might be a way, but I'm going ahead with this way. So I'll be using the secret that is generated and storing that in the DB in order to compare it.